# Java classes, inherited constructor with new

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

What does it mean in the following lines?

```
superclass sc = new subclass();
subclass sc = new superclass();
```

The first line i have seen implemented in my computer science book and i do not know what it means.
How can the super class insantiate new subclass constructor?
The second line how does it even work? I thought that subclass does not inherit superclass constructor?

New to OOP and confused.

Comment: The second line should not compile...

Comment: Kelvin, Your suspicion is correct. It can't ! Constructors are not inherited. Only protected and public properties do.

Comment: @RaviTrivedi it has nothing to do with "constructors are not inherited". A Volkswagen (subclass) is a vehicle (superclass). All Volkswagen are vehicles, so you can treat a reference to a Volkswagen as a reference to a vehicle. Not all vehicles are Volkswagen, so you cannot treat a reference to a vehicle as a reference to a Volkswagen.

Comment: @SJuan76, read his last statement.

Comment: @RaviTrivedi Nevertheless it's irrelevant.

Comment: @EJP, sorry, what is irrelevant here ?

Comment: This question is constructive.  It's probably a duplicate though for anyone who is up for the thankless work of linking the appropriate one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy - second line doesn't compile.  (Tip:  write it out and try it next time.)

First line makes sense.  Perhaps reading it this way will help more?

```
superclass sup;
subclass sub = new subclass();
sup = sub;
```

In any case note that you just plain old *make* a subclass.  Then you can hold onto it in a reference to a super class because a subclass **is** an instance of a super class.

Note this has **nothing** to do with constructor inheritance.  Constructors are *never* inherited.

Answer (score 2):

maybe an example can help you. Think at your 2 lines in that way:

```
//Student extends Person

Person p = new Student();
Student s = new Person();
```

You can easily notice that the first line is correct becase a *Student* **is** a *Person*.
But not all *Persons* are *Students*, so that's why the second line is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It is right that second line will give compilation error.

In the first line, a super class keeps the instance of subclass. Here we can see the "IS a" relationship. For example

```
class Animal {}

class Dog extends Animal {}

class TestCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal a=new Dog(); // here a contains the instance of Dog
    }
}
```